# Range ID's changing due to cell selection

Tags: vba, excel, range, user-defined-functions

32bit Excel 2013 / Win 7 64 bit

UDF asks user for two range inputs from the same table and a lookup value ie:

```
Public Function FindBfromA(A as Range,B as Range, IDValue as Integer)
For IDCheck = 1 to A.Count
    IF A(IDCheck) = IDValue then
        IDNum = IDCheck
        Exit For
    End if
Next IDCheck
FindBfromA = B(IDNum)
End Function
```

Formula is added into another column of the table, for example

```
=FindBfromA([A],[B],[@C])
'Where C is calculated via something
```

My issues is Ranges A & B become disjointed. Where `A(IDCheck)` and `B(IDCheck)` should belong to corresponding columns in the same table row, based on where my cursor is when calculating begins Range [B] will re-key

This then causes the formula to return the wrong value from the `FindBfromA=B(IDNum)` as A(IDNum){Row} <> B(IDNum){Row}

[image]

I couldn't reproduce the error in the workbook I created with the false data - in my company (private) workbook the function operates essentially the same way, but captures two 'B' values given two IDs and passes them to another function.

Comment: What is `IFValue` in your code? Shouldn't it be `IDValue`?

Comment: Sorry, it's correct in my code, it was a typo when I wrote the forum input -- I'll make that update in the ask, but yes, it is "IDValue"

Comment: Why wouldn't you just copy and paste the code?

Comment: I hadn't actually written this code yet, I was creating a dummy version that I could share without violating my company's security protocols and then copied and pasted from the forum into VBA to make sure it worked, and fixed the "IFValue" in excel but forgot to update it in the forum -- all other things stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing your range selections, but the unreliable element of your code is the cell references. By using a single integer index, you are basically selecting the *nth* cell in the range rather than cell on row *n*. My suspicion is that range B is offset from range A by a number of rows. Let's say your two selections were A = "A1:A10" and B = "B2:B11" then A(3), for example, would be on row 3 but B(3) would be on row 4. The same would apply if Range A had more than one column.

To eliminate that risk, refer to the ranges by the row and column indexes, as in the code below. You'll note I've also change the data type of the IDValue to a variant as this prevent an error being thrown in your IDValue should ever be something like a `String` or `Long`. I've also looped through range A with a `For Each` loop on each cell to cater for the case that range A has more than one column.

```
Public Function FindBfromA(A As Range, B As Range, IDValue As Variant) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In A.Cells
        If cell.Value2 = IDValue Then
            FindBfromA = B.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value2
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Ambie,

I need to keep the named range convention, my plan is to port this over to access eventually. Because I'm using tables the numeric placement of the A Range and B Range should always be aligned. It is oddly only an issue if I press enter in a cell in the table, where it resets the range key to correspond to 1 = cursor location. When I use the "Calculate Sheet" it'll work fine.

Thanks for your input - It's a valid observation, just not the issue in this instance.